# How to get specific table cell value by using PHP simple html dom

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

```
             head1 head2 head3 head4 head5
       row1     0    0     0     0    155
       row2     0    0     0     0      8
       row3     0    0     0     0    163
```

Now I want get last value of (163).

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, and be more specific so we know which part of your code you need help with.

Comment: Also, it is kind of a guess work to determine the exact structure of input HTML, because you're only providing the rendered results.

Answer (score 0):

you have updated your question so,on the basis of updated question you can used this code also

```
//$url is your path
$j = new simple_html_dom();
$j = file_get_html($url);

foreach($j->find('table tr') as $row) {
    $cell = $row->find('td', 0);
    echo $cell;
}
```

you need `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` library go this [url](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and download

you can include file like this

```
 require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
```

here is the complete documentation of [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

for specific cell you can used

```
// Example
echo $html->find("#table_id", 0)->children(1)->children(1)->children(2)->id;
// or 
echo $html->getElementById("table_id")->childNodes(1)->childNodes(1)->childNodes(2)->getAttribute('id');
```

i think you should read `HTML DOM Parser Manual`. there is a multiple way to get childNodes

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on null in

Comment: @Karthik i have update my answer used below code and update me if you found any error

Comment: again i got same issue, already i got whole table data, but i want only specific table cell (163). Plz look at the sample table record.

Comment: echo $html->find("#table_id", 0)->children(1)->children(1)->children(2)->id;  In basic how to get the exact value from table without using any id or class.